# Where is the commit object after "git clone ..."?

Tags: git, git-clone

After I typed `git clone <path to project>` I see that `.git/refs/heads/master` was created with `SHA1_code` inside.

Though I see that `SHA1_code` points to a commit object (by typing `git cat-file -t SHA1_code`), I couldn't find this commit object in `.git/objects`.

Where is this commit object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably in a pack

Refer to **[Packfiles](http://progit.org/book/ch9-4.html)** (Pro Git Chapter 9-4) to learn more about the git object database

> The initial format in which Git saves objects on disk is called a loose object format. However, occasionally Git packs up several of these objects into a single binary file called a packfile in order to save space and be more efficient. Git does this if you have too many loose objects around, if you run the git gc command manually, or if you push to a remote server. To see what happens, you can manually ask Git to pack up the objects by calling the git gc command: